# OpenCV- Detecting objects excluding shadows

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm developing a way to detect cars from an aerial view image. I'm using scikit package to calculate the difference of an empty parking lot image and a parking lot with cars to detect the foreign objects. Then I draw the minimum area rectangle around cars.

This works well when there are no shadows.

Empty parking lot image (Please ignore the maroon color car)

[image: Empty parking lot]

Without shadows

[image: Without shadows original]

[image: Without shadows threshold]

[image: Without shadows result]

With shadows (Problem)

When there are car shadows, they are also in the minimum area rectangle. How can I exclude shadows from the rectangle?

[image: With shadows original]

[image: With shadows threshold]

[image: With shadows result]

Here is my source

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import imutils
from cv2 import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
# load the two input images
imageA = cv2.imread('empty-lot.png')
imageB = cv2.imread('two-car-lot-shadow.png')

# convert the images to grayscale
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
# images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True, gaussian_weights=True, sigma=4)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

# threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
# obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the min area rect of the contour and area
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    # remove small contour areas
    if area < 10000: continue
    # convert all coordinates floating point values to int
    box = np.int0(box)
    # draw a green rectangle
    cv2.drawContours(imageB, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# show the output images
cv2.imshow("Modified", imageB)
cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
k = cv2.waitKey() & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    exit()
```

Comment: Try out other color conventions such as HSV, YUV, etc, BGR color domain is not suited for such problems, other color conventions seem favourable in this use case, as the shadow would only  change **intensity** of those pixels, research for those color conventions where intensity is an independent channel. Then you can scrap that channel, while calculating diff on the remaining two channels.

Comment: Cleaver idea! thank you @ZdaR I'll try that and report back!

Comment: It's working, I can remove shadows by removing the V channel! When the camera is noisy or shadow is too dark, the hue value of the dark area goes wild. So sometimes this method fails.

Comment: Then another approach could be to train your own haar cascade, for vehicle detection, you would need to train one for yourself using the images of car top views without shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the image format to HSV, it's easy to remove the shadow.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Union, Callable


def main():
    img_bgr: np.ndarray = cv2.imread(str(Path('parking.jpg')))
    img_hsv: np.ndarray = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(src=img_hsv, lowerb=np.array([0, 64, 153]), upperb=np.array([179, 255, 255]))
    img_hsv_modify: np.ndarray = cv2.bitwise_and(img_bgr, img_bgr, mask=mask)
    # show_img(img_hsv_modify)

    img_mask_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv_modify, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshold_val, img_bit = cv2.threshold(img_mask_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # type: float, np.ndarray
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_bit, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    img_bgr_copy = np.copy(img_bgr)
    for cnt in filter(lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c) > 10000, contours):
        box = cv2.boxPoints(cv2.minAreaRect(cnt))
        cv2.drawContours(img_bgr_copy, [np.int0(box)], -1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

    show_img([img_bgr, img_hsv_modify, cv2.cvtColor(img_bit, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), img_bgr_copy],
             note=['original', 'hsv modify', 'bit', 'result'])
    show_img(img_bgr_copy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And you may ask how do I know the *lower bound* and *upper bound*. (Please see the **extension code: control_bar_hsv.py**)

```py
mask = cv2.inRange(src=img_hsv, lowerb=np.array([0, 64, 153]), upperb=np.array([179, 255, 255]))
```

result:

[image]

all image:

[image]

## Extension code

### show_img:

```py
def show_img(img_list: Union[np.ndarray, List[np.ndarray]], combine_fun: Callable = np.vstack,
             window_name='demo', window_size=(ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) // 2, ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) // 2),
             delay_time=0, note: Union[str, List[str]] = None, **options):
    if isinstance(img_list, np.ndarray):
        img_list = [img_list]

    if isinstance(note, str):
        print(note)

    cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    if window_size:
        w, h = window_size
        cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, w, h)

    result_list = []
    for idx, img in enumerate(img_list):
        img = np.copy(img)
        if note and isinstance(note, list) and idx < len(note):
            cv2.putText(img, note[idx], org=options.get('org', (50, 50)),
                        fontFace=options.get('fontFace', cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX),
                        fontScale=options.get('fontScale', 2), color=(0, 255, 255), thickness=4)
        result_list.append(img)
    cv2.imshow(window_name, combine_fun(result_list))
    cv2.waitKey(delay_time)
```

### control_bar_hsv.py

It's easy to use, just copy and paste and then tell it where is your image path, done.

*and if you want to create other control_bar, maybe `ControlBarBase` will help you write to write less code.*

```
"""
control_bar_hsv.py
"""

import cv2
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import functools
from typing import Tuple, Callable


class ControlBarBase:
    __slots__ = ('img_bgr',)
    WAIT_TIME = 500  # milliseconds
    CONTROL_PANEL_NAME = 'control_panel'
    IMAGE_PANEL_NAME = 'image'
    SCREEN_SIZE: Tuple[int, int] = None

    def __init__(self, img_path: Path):
        self.img_bgr: np.ndarray = cv2.imread(str(img_path))
        self.init_window()
        self.init_track_bar()

    def init_window(self):
        for name in (self.CONTROL_PANEL_NAME, self.IMAGE_PANEL_NAME):
            cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            if self.SCREEN_SIZE:
                screen_width, screen_height = self.SCREEN_SIZE
                cv2.resizeWindow(name, int(screen_width), int(screen_height))

    def init_track_bar(self):
        """
        self.build_track_bar(label_name, range_lim=(0, 255), default_value=0, callback)
        """
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of _ControlBarBase must provide a init_track_bar() method')

    def render(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('subclasses of _ControlBarBase must provide a render() method.')

    def build_track_bar(self, label_name: str,
                        range_lim: Tuple[int, int], default_value: int, callback: Callable = lambda x: ...):
        min_val, max_val = range_lim
        cv2.createTrackbar(label_name, self.CONTROL_PANEL_NAME, min_val, max_val, callback)
        cv2.setTrackbarPos(label_name, self.CONTROL_PANEL_NAME, default_value)

    def get_trackbar_pos(self, widget_name: str):
        return cv2.getTrackbarPos(widget_name, self.CONTROL_PANEL_NAME)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            img, callback_func = self.render()
            cv2.imshow(self.IMAGE_PANEL_NAME, img)
            if (cv2.waitKey(self.WAIT_TIME) & 0xFF == ord('q') or
                    cv2.getWindowProperty(self.IMAGE_PANEL_NAME, 0) == -1 or
                    cv2.getWindowProperty(self.CONTROL_PANEL_NAME, 0) == -1):
                callback_func()
                break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


class ControlBarHSV(ControlBarBase):
    __slots__ = ()
    WAIT_TIME = 500
    SCREEN_SIZE = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 2, ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 2

    def init_track_bar(self):
        self.build_track_bar('HMin', range_lim=(0, 179), default_value=0)
        self.build_track_bar('SMin', (0, 255), 0)
        self.build_track_bar('VMin', (0, 255), 0)

        self.build_track_bar('HMax', (0, 179), 179)
        self.build_track_bar('SMax', (0, 255), 255)
        self.build_track_bar('VMax', (0, 255), 255)

    def render(self):
        # get current positions of all trackbars
        h_min = self.get_trackbar_pos('HMin')
        s_min = self.get_trackbar_pos('SMin')
        v_min = self.get_trackbar_pos('VMin')

        h_max = self.get_trackbar_pos('HMax')
        s_max = self.get_trackbar_pos('SMax')
        v_max = self.get_trackbar_pos('VMax')

        # Set minimum and max HSV values to display
        lower = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
        upper = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])

        # Create HSV Image and threshold into a range.
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
        img_output: np.ndarray = cv2.bitwise_and(self.img_bgr, self.img_bgr, mask=mask)

        @functools.wraps(self.render)
        def cb_func():
            return print(f'cv2.inRange(src=hsv, lowerb=np.array([{h_min}, {s_min}, {v_min}]), upperb=np.array([{h_max}, {s_max}, {v_max}]))')

        return img_output, cb_func


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    arg_parser = ArgumentParser()
    arg_parser.add_argument("src_path", type=Path, help="source image path")
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    obj = ControlBarHSV(args.src_path)  # ControlBarHSV(Path('parking.jpg'))
    obj.run()
```

[image]

Comment: @nipunasudha  2 years, 5 months ago, I hope you already find the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Carson. HSV method was the best we achieved with image processing, and then we switched to YOLO library. Practically our cameras were not directly above the parking spaces, so YOLO could recognize the bounding boxes.